# Any way to make Word table first row repeat when inside other table?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

I'm automating a word document in vb.net. My problem is I need a table within another table to repeat the first row. Is there any way to do this?

The table's textwrap is set to none, and the first row is the only one that has the repeat has header property set.

I CAN'T take the table out of it's containing table. This solution is not an option.

This has nothing to do with the fact that the document is automated too.

Using word 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick test with Word 2010.

I created a table, and checked "repeat as header row at the top of each page".

Sure enough, that worked.

Then I created another table, and cut/pasted the first one into it.

The header was not repeated in the Word UI, although the property remained set.

I had a quick look around for properties which might affect the behaviour of nested tables, but couldn't see any.

Then I googled "word nested table repeat header row", which returns quite a few relevant results.

Conclusion: you can't make a header row in a nested table repeat on subsequent pages.  Tricks like putting it inside a content control didn't seem to work either.

Comment: No problem, if this is the correct answer, or helpful, you can say thanks by clicking accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to close the question too soon, maybe someone is going to find a way. To be honest, I would've prefered an answer with a solution to my problem. I'll select your post as the answer if nothing better comes up.